# Accessing the list within a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have created a dictionary

```
store = {'assetType': "['props','char','env','sets']", 'Height': '871', 'Project': 'AnimationProject1', 'Width': '2048', 'FPS': '24', 'Type': 'Animation', 'Unit': 'cm'}
```

This is within an xml file, so I use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the file and `find`, `findall` and `iter` to access the xml files and the above line is what I got at the end. I use a for loop to access the xml file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

read = xml.parse(xmlFile)
#xmlFile is the xmlFile directory

findBase = read.findall('base')
#'base' and 'type' are the xml.SubElement used in the xml file.

for child in findBase:
    findType = child.iter('type')
    store = child.attrib
    for types in findType:
        store[types.attrib.keys()[0]] = types.attrib.values()[0]
    print store
    print store.items()[0][1][3]
```

However, now I would like access `'props'` from `'assetType'` from the dictionary above. I tried using `store.items()[0][1]` and I'm able to get `"['props','char','env','sets']"` but when I do `store.items()[0][1][3]`, instead of getting the word `sets`, I get `r` instead. I understand the reason behind it, it's because it has registered that whole line as a string instead of a list of characters. I have also tried something like `store.get("assetType")` The problem is the same.

My question is, how can I get the word `props`, `char`, `env` or `sets` as a whole from the dictionary above instead of individual letters?

Thanks

Comment: `from ast import literal_eval; literal_eval("['props','char','env','sets']")`

Comment: Convert your XML to JSON then load it as a dictionary. Then start a new career as JSON evangelist. http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/05/27/and-thats-how-good-old-xml-disappeared/

Answer (score 0):

The `assetType` value is a string as you mentioned that needs to be parsed into a list. A couple ways to do it as mentioned in the comments. Here's a simple JSON way that's unfortunately fairly specific to your case. The single quotes have are not valid JSON so they have to be swapped for doubles.

```
>>> import json
>>> store = {'assetType': "['props','char','env','sets']", 
 'Height': '871', 'Project': 'AnimationProject1', 
 'Width': '2048', 'FPS': '24', 'Type': 'Animation', 
 'Unit': 'cm'}
>>> json.loads(store['assetType'].replace("'",'"'))[3]
u'sets'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the input you can do an `eval` on the string representation of your list to convert it into a proper Python list

```
store = {'assetType': "['props','char','env','sets']", 'Height': '871', 'Project': 'AnimationProject1', 'Width': '2048', 'FPS': '24', 'Type': 'Animation', 'Unit': 'cm'}
asset_types = eval(store['assetType'])
# Then access the entries in the list
print asset_types[0]  # etc.
```